# SQLPLUS object system. is invalid

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I'm stuck with some simple procedure and I can't figure out why.
This is my code, which I'm running in sqlplus:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NormalizeName(fullname IN NVARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT TRIM(fullname) INTO fullname FROM DUAL;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(fullname);
END NormalizeName;
/

BEGIN
    NormalizeName('Alice Wonderland   ');
END;
/
```

When I run it, I get the error:

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

        NormalizeName('Alice Wonderland   ');
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.NORMALIZENAME is invalid
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Never create objects in the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` schema.  Those are reserved for Oracle.  If you want to create objects, create a new schema first.

2) When you see that a procedure has been created with compilation errors in SQL*Plus, type `show errors` to see the errors.

3) The error appears to be that your `SELECT` statement is trying to write to the `fullname` parameter.  But that parameter is defined as an `IN` parameter, not `IN OUT`, so it is read-only.  If you define the parameter as `IN OUT`, though, you could not pass a string constant to the procedure, you'd need to define a local variable in your calling block.  It doesn't make a lot of sense to have a procedure that doesn't do anything other than call `dbms_output` since there is no guarantee that anyone will see the data written to that buffer.  My guess is that you really want a function that returns a normalized name.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NormalizeName( p_full_name IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN TRIM( p_full_name );
END;
```

which you can then call

```
DECLARE
  l_normalized_name VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  l_normalized_name := NormalizeName( 'Alice Wonderland     ' );
  dbms_output.put_line( l_normalized_name );
END;
```

If you really need a procedure because this is a homework assignment

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NormalizeName( p_fullname IN VARCHAR2 )
AS
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line( TRIM( p_fullname ));
END;
```

In the real world, you should only be using procedures when you want to manipulate the state of the database (i.e. you're doing `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE`, etc.).  You use functions when you want to perform calculations without changing the state of the database or when you want to manipulate data passed in parameters.

Comment: I actually do need a procedure and not a function, this is just some homework for my course. That's why it's so simple and doesn't do much more than trimming and dbms. "show error" says "expression 'FULLNAME' cannot be used as an INTO-target" which confirms that the issue is that fullname is read only, however I cannot present a function as a solution because I'm asked to write a procedure.

Comment: @PrincessLilly - I've updated the answer with an example of a procedure.  That's not something you'd use a procedure for in reality.

Comment: Thank you. The actual exercise I need to do is more complex than this, but I am now able to understand what was wrong in my code.